# using ipywidgets SelectMultiple on a dataframe

Tags: dataframe, datagrid, ipywidgets

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import ipywidgets as widgets
from IPython.display import display 

a = ['Banking', 'Auto', 'Life', 'Electric', 'Technology', 'Airlines', 
'Healthcare']
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(7, 4), columns = list('ABCD'))
df.index = a

df.head(7)


dropdown = widgets.SelectMultiple(
                        options=df.index,
                        description='Sector',
                        disabled=False,
                        layout={'height':'100px', 'width':'40%'})
display(dropdown)
```

I want to create a function where I can filter the df by Sector. i.e say I select Airlines, Banking and Electric from the display(dropdown) and it returns a dataframe of the selected sectors only.

Comment: Can you post your code for what you have so far? If you can create some fake data that will be much easier to work with.

Comment: Sure thing. Here you go!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try something like this, I have used a global variable to demonstrate in this case, but I would normally wrap up the functionality in a class so you always have access to the filtered dataframe.

Rather than use interact I have used `.observe` on the Selection widget.

```py
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import ipywidgets as widgets
from IPython.display import display, clear_output

a = ['Banking', 'Auto', 'Life', 'Electric', 'Technology', 'Airlines', 
'Healthcare']
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(7, 4), columns = list('ABCD'), index=a)

filtered_df = None


dropdown = widgets.SelectMultiple(
                        options=df.index,
                        description='Sector',
                        disabled=False,
                        layout={'height':'100px', 'width':'40%'})

def filter_dataframe(widget):
    global filtered_df
    selection = list(widget['new'])

    with out:
        clear_output()
        display(df.loc[selection])
        filtered_df = df.loc[selection]

out = widgets.Output()
dropdown.observe(filter_dataframe, names='value')
display(dropdown)
display(out)
```

Comment: I found this answer incredibly helpful. I also swapped out `display(df.loc[selection])` for `display(df[ df['column_name'].isin(selection)])` in case you want to view something other than the index.